# Javascript make new object accessible in all scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a login script on a node.js server, so when a user logs in, I create a new object for that user, for example:

```
// MOCK-UP: NOT ACTUAL CODE

db.query('QUERY', function(err, rows, fields){

        if(!err){

           var User = new _User(row[0].id, row[0].name, ...);
           // Continue on

        } else { throw err }

});
```

Now how can I make it so that I still create a new _User object every time somebody logs in **and** make it globally accessible. I want to store all current user information in a class and be able to easily retrieve it at any point of time as well as use all the class methods.

**EDIT**: I don't know if just initializing `var Player;` somewhere at the top is a good idea since it will be overwritten. Yeah, I need some advice :)

**P.S.**: login script is within a socket event, and I don't mind to re-write the code to fit the adjustments!

**P.P.S:** I don't want to store the info inside of the socket.

Comment: You can't use a single global to keep track of a user in a server environment because all user's requests access the same set of globals so different users will just trounce on each other's data.  What you want here is a session.  I'd suggest using Express and express-session.  That will automatically make a session object for each user available to all request handlers.  You can then store whatever you want in that session object and it will be available just for that user's requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 But same thing is with a socket though, isn't it? That's what I'm currently using, but would like to have a separate user class.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `But same thing is with a socket though, isnt'it?`  If a socket represents a connection to a user, you can just add a `.user` property to the socket object itself.

Comment: well, storing data for a specific user inside of a socket. For example, socket.username, socket.uID, etc (socket.io framework)

Comment: You can add custom properties to a socket.io object just fine.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  This question is very unclear.

Comment: Ahh okay, so potentially I could add a prototype to the socket object?

Comment: No, no reason to add a prototype unless you want to add your own methods.  Just add a property to store data: `socket._user = User`.

Comment: I do want to have methods. The way you showed with `socket._user = User` where User is an object with methods, would I be able to call them the same way: `socket._user.subscribe(link)` etc?

Comment: Then add a prototype to the constructor for your `User` object, not to socket.  You seem to have wandered pretty far off-topic here.

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what I asked, actually. If you could copy&paste your last few comments as an answer, I'll mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a socket represents a connection to a user, you can just add a `socket._user` property to the socket object itself.  If you then want methods on your `User` object, you can add a prototype to the `User` constructor.